# which certbot software can be removed after installing certificates automatically?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I installed certificates on my (nginx) web server (ubunu 18).

The process required a PPA and software I presumably don't need **anymore**.

What can be safely uninstalled, while **keeping** my certificates on the host?

---

This is what was installed via sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-nginx:

The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-acme python3-certbot python3-certbot-nginx python3-configargparse python3-future python3-icu python3-josepy python3-mock python3-ndg-httpsclient python3-parsedatetime
  python3-pbr python3-pyparsing python3-requests-toolbelt python3-rfc3339 python3-tz python3-zope.component python3-zope.event python3-zope.hookable

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  certbot python-certbot-nginx python3-acme python3-certbot python3-certbot-nginx python3-configargparse python3-future python3-icu python3-josepy python3-mock python3-ndg-httpsclient
  python3-parsedatetime python3-pbr python3-pyparsing python3-requests-toolbelt python3-rfc3339 python3-tz python3-zope.component python3-zope.event python3-zope.hookable

Answer (score 0):

Certificates remain in any case, they are configuration the package wouldn't purge.

An ACME client is needed for cert renewal. Which for Let's Encrypt is every 30 days to be sure it won't expire after 90.

---

If these packages are to be removed anyway:

```
# Remove what you explicitly installed
apt remove certbot python3-certbot-nginx
# Remove unneeded dependencies
apt autoremove
# Remove remaining PPA packages, reinstall any provided by the main distro
apt install ppa-purge
ppa-purge ppa:certbot/certbot
```